# Next.js: __next div causing css style failure

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to move my old static HTML project into Next.js, but the extra

```
<div id="__next">
```

is blocking some of class in my css stylesheet(eg. `body` > `section`).

I tried to remove the extra div in inspect mode and it works. Just wondering how to remove it from the rendering? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: you can remove > or give class name for css. it's useful to use class

Answer (score 0):

> For class based react (can also use in constructor, componentWillMount will be deprecated)

```
componentWillMount() {
    let tar = document.getElementById('__next');
    tar.parentNode.innerHTML = tar.children[0].innerHTML;
 }
```

> For react hook (Functional component)

```
useEffect(()=>{
        let tar = document.getElementById('__next');
        tar.parentNode.innerHTML = tar.children[0].innerHTML;
    })
```